# Meaning of 'vector' in asm context

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, system-calls, terminology

For something like:

```
int $0x80
```

I understand that it is executing the `int` instruction on the destination operand value `0x80` or `128`. And, if I'm understanding correctly, `128` is a system call and it'll execute the call that is stored in `eax`. However, what is the meaning of `vector` here?

> The destination operand specifies a **vector** from 0 to 255, encoded as an 8-bit unsigned intermediate value.

Why not just use the word `number` here? Is there a specific meaning of vector here (and I suppose it's different than the meaning in C++ or math).

Comment: Let me google that for you: https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/interrupt-vector.  Or for x86 specifically, historically the table of interrupt handler pointers was called the IVT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_vector_table.  Protected mode uses a "descriptor" table that has metadata besides just the pointer.

Comment: As for the etymology, "vector" makes sense: it's a direction to go in, where to send execution.

Comment: From Intel's _Basic Architecture_ volume, section 6.4 Vectors and Interrupts: "Each interrupt and exception in the IDT is identified with a number, called a vector"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term vector in this type of low level software context is a list of addresses, vectors.  Often based on interrupts/exceptions.  So the handler for interrupt 5 is the 5th (well 6th sometimes do the interrupts start with 0 or 1 (generically not specific to x86)).

So the int 0x80 itself is not a vector, but there is a vector table and offset 0x80 in that table is an address to the handler for that interrupt.  That allows for a fixed size item in an easy to look up table, but the size of the handler can vary in size.

It would not be incorrect to call this interrupt 128, but the handler is based ona  vector table.  Which is another word for address.